# Live Property Explorer: What does the horizontal "strikeout" line mean?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, debugging

When you are looking at the properties of a visual WPF element in the Visual Studio Live Property Explorer, what does it mean when a property has a horizontal line through it the way that the `MinHeight` property does below?

[image]

If the [MS docs explain this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/inspect-xaml-properties-while-debugging?view=vs-2022) I see all sort of discussions of what various visual aspects mean (e.g. green vs yellow) but I'm not seeing anyone talk about this line.  I'm sure it's something simple but I wonder if anyone knows the definitive answer.  I'm embarrassed I don't know this, given how long I've used this tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what does it mean when a property has a horizontal line through

the value for the same property can be set multiple times, see [Dependency property value precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/dependency-property-value-precedence?view=netdesktop-7.0)

obviously, only one value (with highest priority) can be used

when you inspect Live Properties of element, values which are strike-through are assigned somewhere (e.g. default, inherited, set in a Style) but ignored in favor of more important setting (e.g. local value)

Answer (score 1):

I added a button control in WPF, and specified some properties in the property bar, such as Background, Content, Width, etc. There is a red cross on the right side of the specified properties in the property bar, as shown in the figure:

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I open the Live Property Explorer, all assigned properties in the button (or in other words, all properties with a red cross on the right in the property bar) have a horizontal bar.

[image]

[image]

[image]

In short, all properties with dashes in the Live Property Explorer have been assigned or have fixed values before being debugged. For example, the MinHeight you mentioned has a horizontal bar in the Live Property Explorer because its value is zero, while MaxHeight has no horizontal bars in the Live Property Explorer because it is infinity.